# ExtJS EditorGridPanel and the column renderer

Tags: javascript, extjs, editor, grid

I'm a little confused by the following documentation for the [EditorGrid](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel):

> Editing is performed on the value of
>   the field specified by the column's
>   dataIndex in the backing Store (so if
>   you are using a renderer in order to
>   display transformed data, this must be
>   accounted for).

I'm not really sure how to "account for" my renderer in the following situation:

```
...

columns : [{
                header   : 'Foo',
                width    : 100,
                dataIndex: 'foo',
                renderer: function(value, p, record) {return value? value.bar: ""},  
                editor : new Ext.form.TextField({  
                    allowBlank : false  
                })
            }]
...
```

As you can see, this renderer is a really simple one, but this is clearly not going to work with a TextField. I understand why it will just display my foo object and not the bar property when the user edits.

So how does one get around this? Should I be overwriting the `Ext.form.TextField` with a new `setValue` and `getValue`? I thought about using the events `beforeedit` and `afteredit`, but that seems like overkill. I feel like I'm missing something very simple here.

In case I'm not being clear, here's a few screens of the result I'm getting:

**Column Renderer Works!**
[image: yay renderer]

**Ext.form.TextField gets an object**
[image: booo textfield]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change how the column displays the `value` you HAVE to change the column renderer and the editor to reflect this. That means, yes, you will have to listen to and act on before and after edit events.

(If you think about it, for example, I change the 7 to a 9. How would the system know what to do with this 9 since your value is a totally different format and in fact an object on its own. the only way to convert is to take the 9 and covert it back into whatever object you want which means, listening for before/after edit and pushing, pulling values from the editor to/from backing record.)

Comment: That makes sense to me.  I guess I'm not sure exactly what I should be changing in the before and after event.  How do I gain access to the editor?  I have the "event.grid" and "event.record", so I'm guessing it's in grid somewhere :) .

Comment: It seems like there should be an easier way to do this, as my data transformation is so simple.

Comment: I'm marking this as correct, but honestly, I don't see a good way of doing this.  I overwrote the startEditing method, and then in the afteredit event I change things back.  That's sloppy.  I'm guessing the real way to do this is to write an extension of Ext.form.Field that displays your object correctly, and somehow allows editing correctly.

Comment: The problem is, the display part is not done by the form.Field. it is done by the grid.Column. So I agree that there needs to be a better way (is there in 4.0?) but I don't know of one today than to listen to before/after edit (Once you have the before/after edit logic, you can put this inline or extend form.Field if you think you need to reuse it. +1 to your question, btw

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I hope ExtJS 4 gives us an easier way to do this.  I also see what you are saying about how the display isn't handled in the field.  What a strange place for the grid to fall short.  I would think this would be a common occurrence.  Cheers mate!